# how to block my laravel website in any version of specific browser like internet explorer due my design is not compatible?

Tags: laravel

I want to know how to not open or prevent to access my website in any version of browser such as internet explorer because of my design doesn't compatible in browser. So, I want to know how block the website.. using laravel?

Can you describe in controller? Or write the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these ways

```
$request->headers->get('User-Agent')

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

get_browser();
```

Then you can just use a switch case to compare the browser version with specific version you want. And then you can redirect or abort or whatever action you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i dont know where controller can i put it?

Comment: You should put it in middleware, not a controller. you should block the request to your application and redirect back the user to a specific page you want.